# How to scroll within a ScrollView while keyboard is present?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView and two buttons, one is at the top of the view and the second one is set lower than the height of the keyboard. By changing the inset, I now have the ScrollView move up once the second button is pressed and the keyboard is shown. However, after I press the second button and the keyboard moves the ScrollView up, I want to scroll the view up with a touch to be able to see the first button (without closing the keyboard). But whenever I try to pull it up the keyboard disappears. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you adjust only the content insets of the scroll view when the keyboard appears, you shouldn't have any problems as the scroll view will still be scrollable in its new size. Do you have any code using `view.endEditing` for example? This could be causing what you're describing, the keyboard closing as soon as you touch the scroll view, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Oops I accidentally had Dismiss on drag option enabled for the keyboard setting on the ScrollView. Works perfectly now.